# Can't install El Capitan in VirtualBox on High Sierra

Tags: macos, install, high-sierra, virtualbox

I am installing El Capital in VirtualBox on High Sierra. The reason I am doing this is that I have an enterprise application that stoped working in High Sierra and so I am going the VM route.

When I need to select a disk to install the OS, there is no option for me to choose except the dmg file.

[image: No disk to select]

I am guessing that it might be the APFS on my MacBook Pro that is causing the problem but I have no solution. I tried using a USB external drive but it does not appear too after plugging in.

Does anyone have a way around this?

Comment: You have to create and add some VirtualDiskImage file (vdi) as virtual hard disk to the VM and partition/format it with Disk Utility (menubar > Utlities > Disk Utility) first. Then you will be presented with a r/w volume to install OS X to.

Comment: When I create a new VM, it already asked me to add a vdi file. But how do I partition it using Disk Utility as I could not see the drive on my Disk Utility? I only see a Macintosh HD on the left sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just figured out that you have to click view>all devices in Disk Utility before you can see the virtual drive and format it or install to it!